# How to set list of values as parameter into hibernate query?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

For example, I have this query

```
 select cat from Cat cat where cat.id in :ids
```

and I want to set ids to list (1,2,3,4,5,6,17,19).

This code doesn't work

```
session.createQuery("select cat from Cat cat where cat.id in :ids")
       .setParameter("ids", new Long[]{1,2,3,4,5})
```

As the result I would like to have SQL query like `id in (1,2,3,4)`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use [`setParameterList()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-). You'll also have to put parenthesis around the list param.

```
session.createQuery("select cat from Cat cat where cat.id in (:ids)").setParameterList("ids", new Long[]{1,2,3,4,5})
```

Comment: `setParameterList` is depcreated in newer hibernate.  How do we pass this in?  I tried using `setparameter` and didn't get correct behavior...

Comment: yes setParameterList is deprecated and i could not get correct behavior too, any update?