# Hibernate HQL NOT IN clause doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

```
// a is some String and bList is some list of type ArrayList
String findQuery = "SELECT T FROM " + MyClass.class.getName() + " T where a = :itemA and (b NOT IN (:bList))";
Query query = factory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(findQuery);
query.setParameter("itemA", a);
query.setParameter("bList", bList);
```

This is the query I am executing. Instead of giving me results where `a = itemA and b is not in bList`, it gives me results where `a = itemA and b IS IN bList`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about **and NOT (b IN (:bList))** ?

Comment: @Hogan it's not SQL but HQL. Query (not NativeQuery) is created see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584898/how-to-set-list-of-values-as-parameter-into-hiberante-query

Comment: Please, enable the SQL log and see a SQL request is produced by Hibernate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String findQuery = "SELECT T FROM " + MyClass.class.getName() + " T where T.a =:itemA and T.b NOT IN (:bList)";
Query query = factory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(findQuery);
query.setParameter("itemA", a);
query.setParameterList("bList", bList);
```

Comment: I tried exactly that (before I even tried the solution I posted in my question), and it wasn't working.

Long story short, I had another process running that was deleting the records I wanted to pull, which is why my result set was empty.

Moral of the story: Don't be an idiot