# StringJoiner - each item in parenthesis

Tags: java, string

To fit a SQL template in a Java app, I need to format elements as follows:

```
RIGHT JOIN (values (123), (456), (789)..
```

In particular, given a Java list of integers:

```
List<int> ints = Arrays.asList(123, 456, 789)
```

How can I correctly use [StringJoiner (examples)](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/10/java-8-stringjoiner/) to output the following string?

```
(123), (456), (789)
```

The closest example I can find is

```
StringJoiner mystring = new StringJoiner(",", "(", ")");
```

Which returns

```
(123, 456, 789)
```

---

**More Background/Context**

MadProgrammer pointed out that I may approach this differently via `PreparedStatement`.  Here is the actual query I'm trying to fill...

So for example, here is a snippet of the query in *native SQL*:

```
SELECT loadlist.id as load_id, payload
FROM payload_log
     RIGHT JOIN (values (123), (456), (789)) as loadlist(id)
            ON payload_log.entity_id = loadlist.id;
```

And here is how it's being called from application.  Ideally we could bind using the `:ids` parameter, but not sure how so was going to do String.format w/ the joiner.

```
String queryString = String.format("SELECT loadlist.id as load_id, payload\n"+
        "FROM payload_log" +
        "     RIGHT JOIN (values (:ids)) as loadlist(id)" +
        "          ON payload_log.entity_id = loadlist.id)";
return entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString).setParameter("ids", loadIds);
```

Now I should be able to pass the `:ids` parameter using `query.setParameter` after applying formatting as in answers below?  So where does a `PreparedStatement` fit in?

Comment: You many need to do this manually, but if you're using SQL, you should be using `PreparedStatement` anyway.  One idea "might" be to map each element, so that it wraps each value in brackets, then you could join them

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are right, it may not be a problem with integers, but in general this could easily allow SQL injection.

Comment: @Clashsoft I might consider using `StringJoiner` or similar approaches to generate the variable length place holders (`(?)`) for the query string, but generally, I always prefer `PreparedStatement`

Comment: @MadProgrammer - let me update my code w/ actual SQL I'm using.  I'd like to understand how to do that more correctly

Comment: *"So where does a PreparedStatement fit in?"*, well, that would depend on what `entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString)` is doing, but the inclusion of `setParameter("ids", loadIds)` suggest that it's doing it already - so you'd only need to pass in the `List` of values to `setParameter` BUT we don't have knowledge of the underlying frameworks you're using

Comment: So I did try this and I was unable to get the formatting correct using setParameter.  Tried several ways, but looks like the old way to do it is deprecated?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584898/how-to-set-list-of-values-as-parameter-into-hibernate-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `StringJoiner`

```java
        List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(123, 456, 789);
        StringJoiner mystring = new StringJoiner("),(", "(", ")");
        ints.forEach(i -> mystring.add(String.valueOf(i)));
        
        System.out.println( mystring );
```

With java `Collectors.joinig()`:

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(123, 456, 789);
ints.stream().map(i -> "(" + String.valueOf(i) + ")").collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me to `Collectors` :D

Answer (score 4):

With your existing code, the easiest way is to add the parentheses to your separator:

```
StringJoiner mystring = new StringJoiner("), (", "(", ")");
// add...
// (123), (456), (789)
```

Or just use the [collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```
String s = Arrays.asList(123, 456, 789)
    .stream()
    .map(Object::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.joining("), (", "(", ")"));
// (123), (456), (789)
```

Better to use prepared statements though instead of using string manipulation to build queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Stream API to map each number to a string, `( n )` and then collect the Stream using [`Collectors#joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) with `,`  as the delimiter.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(123, 456, 789);

        String result = ints.stream().map(n -> "(" + String.valueOf(n) + ")").collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
(123), (456), (789)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use [`PreapredStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)** and positioned parameters.  This should be your first port of call and will save you a lot of potential head aches.

Having said that, just for some fun...

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(123, 456, 789);
String joined = ints.stream().map(x -> "(" + x + ")").collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
System.out.println(joined);
```

Prints `(123), (456), (789)`

Comment: Sorry - is `PreparedStatement` unrelated to your solution here?

Comment: @AdamHughes Yes, I just pointed out that I'd investigate `PreparedStatement` first, but provided a "possible" solution that would meet the requirements of the question asked